# Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '8.2.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, build.gradle

I have a problem synchronizing the build.gradle, apparently compatibility with versions, I will leave the codes of the build.gradle(:app), the build.gradle(myproject), the settings, gradle and wrapper.gradle

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.appdenuncias'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appdenuncias"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx")
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
}
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.21' apply false
    id("com.google.gms.google-services") version "4.3.15" apply false
}
```

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.PREFER_SETTINGS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

rootProject.name = "appdenuncias"
include ':app'
```

```
#Sat Jul 01 18:17:37 CLT 2023
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

I have tried to change the versions, without success so far, other errors appear or the same with another version, what I am looking for is a possible solution to this error to be able to continue, thank you very much everyone